# Why is the answer of multiplying 1.2 by 3 equal to 3.5999999999999996 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this beat
`console.log(1.2 * 3);`
But the answer is 3.5999999999999996

I use console.log((1.2 * 3).toFixed(2)).
And it was done
But what is the reason for this bug?